# How can I get a list of users that have logged in via SSH?

Tags: ssh, logs

I would like to audit how often users log into my Ubuntu system remotely. How can I get a list of users that have logged in via SSH for a particular period of time? (for example, the last 24 hours?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `last` serves exactly this purpose.

```
last -F
```

will give you a list of who logged in, from where, when and how long they were logged in.

Have a look at `man last` to see additional parameters you can use.